# How to obtain a specific frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Does anyone know what are the equations for this oscillator? At the output, I need to obtain a frequency of 1kHz, but I can't find the right equations. Also, my teacher told me to remove I1, but without it it doesn't work, since there is no noise in the circuit, how could I remove it then?

Comment: Go google "phase shift oscillator using op-amp"

Comment: @Andyaka i see the winds of change blowing :) for same advice my posts were edited and deleted five years ago :)))

Comment: @GregoryKornblum An yll wynde, that blowth no man to good, men saie.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum that's too long ago for me to remember details LOL. Did someone come down hard on you back then? Was it me (shuddering in disbelief)?

Comment: No, not you :))) But yes, they moderated me heavily. I even went on a microwar on a guy, not sure he paid attention.

Answer (score 0):

This is true of simulations that have no noise or initial condition unlike Falstad's [web simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZIDYDMAWATKg7HOgJwAciqclIcE21EcApgLSKIBQASiNphLXxDNMJcCHT0oFKQn6Q47LCAAmASwD2yxgFtNjADYAdAM78kkPIkzo42MkTvIY2FnjF1%207ZT0Ho6vCDZ-FQ0tXS0jU3YAcx9AxH9BK0wxMHYAJzj3Xw8oMER0WCLimA5Mm1yK8VyUfMKSho5YqqDxWyRMFM8lNT1wg2ZcxEgSEgaS9BZRWrtUHhA%20T28qvza6VrpesL19Qa41sSrhafFJFGlz2SgFbkxULoX7oRFDs7RZd9T5RRStnR3mBIIJhIBVxrBECwiFJMHA8EQEYikQjzEQwHMCOAvI8Uqs7ikNiE%20gD0DEcUgEuTkqkMuTgU9VnI6uDimVqHg5gwOdUvsyWRCyXC5q0hR0HmlvKLVqLCYgAHJwtj7UVcubHV40GRauQ3ECoUZifWidUQCSay7a67Yo08m2yhWWbBku2Uu2dGmZG0QG2MvIFfkCzLIOCcpBgEM8pn%20gP5MnB4WU%20NimneJOrJOE4wAB1UAGMWFoAGYAQwArvoAC77JOBcNql6mt4XT46-ZEd0QdspE2nTXDBD9r4KbxdnmjwlFsuV5j6RjKMnjynjjtYzKjzvu321aMBtkJE77yN%20%20q7uN2Cnrc-U7oE9DaMREUEuViIY8x-LiCxArGp8-pq%20Uusd7VuegTnj2ZqBPI5hXCgCh8BI2BgKI5C0Hg-jIWIiAAPr3NhYDYdYcCYNhwztpQmCIHgZDovkmBEKg%20HQKU%20HYdgpHYaSCE8Jh2C8Dw6ECUMuEkQRRHoGx8hsXAaCsexOESZO5ZVtxfi0Px6AkCk2CCd6ImseJklwKR2AjHJuGcaRcqLJg7CqUhSCoKaWk8ScjF4WJNgkcZKA4QR7GMVxYASIgDg8AaOl0Og%20pYfpBEJDYxnDNgTCAuxMkJCw6A4Th8mWQAkiYABuxgmAAanZwULOmTkLAxrkPnFhFeUZTF%20Wx2FEJxlUSNY-j8fRcyRY1HnNYQrUoCQ5ldRJ8qUSIPXUO6qF6rxmGBCRo1Ed5bXmVY3XccR2n8U5ojDRtTWGaZPmQKJHX7bNDpKtxFDCrV6G0OtSB4JdLXXbt-mkT9QUSK9PD8R9QlYT9W02BJ-2%20XtwNWYqTrccg-ErcgEVfXxv3ERNkDtexeMg2G-F8QSyFnbp4P4-DUlwMl5mk9h2Z5gWjAlspi1EImtVENySEnCl%20M7YjgOi2TfP9SkgtDbTouw%20N-0JGZkvGYpXNThWzAADIAKIACImAAFJwAD0ACaACUvNvYEtXC4cBHK%20LRPmYUB1VfVlOOWhlSu3dhnGSlsmA17Em5qWxgVuo2gmAUugABbaIthTaQamm4jFemjQkp2EZAyIl0iLDkKR5c-YDgWLZRQ0GoN4i5yAXX57gyGkZA2AOIQ9zWLCODZVMlesOxgMzYtthnQap3Nwem13QXnemfRpcl3g5eMZCrDV-dJFk-ctAGpD0UHjDS8d1NILr6XW%20j1RSPeyFMAzyhyA5yLAWX4XN%2038i98d6P0luxMmoxj6iHlvPdwxl26F1Xv-JEm9WDbyrizTWi0xjhRQrVM%20LsmrLymqlXgo9RYRwIqSAAHnqNwJAByhRAI3RhIBOClQAI5J3UKndg1C8DoBfhiNEYZoTaRSMnAw%20h1DsFzIw8gjCIBkGFKBPIRREHIl5LGIAA) includes for all reactive parts (e.g. 1mV)

A better design for an oscillator with very high Q that ramps up slowly due to the bandwidth of your filters is to precharge the voltage to the desired peak voltage OR include an offset current or voltage on power up Pullup or Vcc/2 for example.

### Fast-Start: Offset decaying DC current example : By design.

This is really easy to do with 0V on every cap on initial condition when you use a single supply version of this circuit. Using Vcc/2 bias on Vin+, the caps will need to have Vcc/2 DC across them for DC blocking so using the R to 0V essentially pre-biases the Cap current from 0V to Vcc/2 (thru R's) and the peak waveform you desire at the start.

Of course, saturation voltages may prohibit full output swing, but now you have a real initial condition of Vcc/2 on the cap and the energy to start oscillating immediately instead of slowly building up with a loop gain just "a bug's whisker" over +1. ( or enough to overcome component tolerances and have soft limiting.)

I have given you 2 hints on how to solve this. One was loop gain >= +1 ( after 180 deg)

Further reading : Barhausen Criteria

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps for deriving the "equations for the oscillator":

- Start with the general oscillation condition (Barkhausen): Unity loop gain at the desired oscillation frequency wo.
- For this purpose, find the transfer function H(jw) for the 3rd-order C-R highpass. Then, the loop gain is LG(jw)=(H(jw) * Av) with Av: Voltage gain of the inverting amplifier.
- Because the loop gain LG(jw=jwo) must be real the function H(jw=jwo) must also be real. The numerator of H(jw) will be imaginary. Therefore, the denominator D(jw=jwo) must also be imaginary. Hence, set the real part of the denominator equal to zero.
- Solve the equation Re(denominator H)=0 and find the frequency wo for which H(jwo) is real.
- Inserting this frequency wo into H(jw) and find the real value of H(w=wo) which is the highpass damping factor a at wo (result must be real).
- Now set the loop gain LG equal to unity: LG(w=wo)=a*Av=1. Now you can find the required gain Av of the amplifier.
- Comment: The gain Av should be made slightly larger than calculated (perhaps app. lager by 5...10%) because of (1) safe start of oscillation and (2) the small error you have made by ignoring the fact that the highpass is loaded by a large resistor (in your case 20k).
  You do not need the pulse I1 - instead, give any of the capacitors an intial value for a safe start of oscillation.